# How to track form abandonment in google tag manager with GA4

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to track form submissions and form abandonment in my website. I'm using google tag manager and google analytics 4.

The GA4 is using the measurement ID instead of the tracking ID. And All the available resources on the internet are demonstrated with a tracking id.

Had anyone worked on a similar case before?

Answer (score 0):

Do you follow Julien from Measureschool? He has a video on exactly your problem

https://youtu.be/_ZXJZh9SQzU

Comment: Thank you sharing this, but this is for universal analytics, and not for GA4 :/